# Поочереди вытащить SIN(X) из выражения SIN(SIN(20 + 20)) + COS(20)

Tags: регулярные-выражения, .net, c#

Проблема в том, что регулярка должна вытаскивать первое совпадение с парным количеством скобок. То есть по логике программы, из этого выражения она должна вытянуть

```
0:SIN(20 + 20)
1:20+20
```

Или еще пример:

```
SIN(20) + SIN(SIN(30) - SIN(40))
```

должна вытянуть:

```
0:SIN(20)
1:20
```

А из

```
SIN(20 - SIN(40))
```

должна вытянуть:

```
0:SIN(40)
1:40
```

**Язык C#, .NET 4.0!**

Comment: А Вы уверены, что эту задачу надо решать через регулярные выражения ?
Может быть правильнее парсить эту арифметику, как это делает компилятор.

Comment: Здесь явно нужно использовать "ленивый" regexp. Тогда с ним можно вычленить самый первый sin(x). И в случае с
<pre>SIN(20) + SIN(SIN(30) - SIN(40))</pre>
ответ будет как раз SIN(20), а не SIN(40)).
Кстати, вопрос для уточнения - X что должно из себя представлять? Выражение из цифр или из букв также (например, названия переменных)?

Comment: SIN(X)
Где X может быть тем же SIN(Y), или выражением Z * Z + Y или просто константным числом, например 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
SIN\(([^()]+)\)
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает :)!

Answer (score 2):

Ай, не решаются такие задачи регулярками, сделайте лучше на конечных автоматах.

**UPD**

Да, есть замечательный алгоритм, называется "рекурсивный спуск"
на нём можно построить парсер математических выражений, с переменными функциями и прочими радостями, попробуйте погуглить и реализовать. Если нужно и у меня будет время - то изложу ентот алгоритм с примерами

Comment: Подобным алгоритмом(свой велосипед) я делаю операции сложения, вычитания, умножения и деления. Так же научил программу работать с приоритетными скобками.

P.S. Сначала написал велосипед, а потом узнал о алгоритме :)! Совет для новичков: ищите лучше!